# How to create n number of arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a following code which works perfectly and does a trick I need.

However I want this code to run for n number of times and create n arrays.

My dataset is:

[image]

My code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Const startRow As Long = 2
    Const valueCol As Long = 2
    Const outputCol As Long = 4
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, valueCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim inputArr As Variant
    inputArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, valueCol), ws.Cells(lastRow, valueCol)).Value
    
    Dim outputSize As Long
    outputSize = ((UBound(inputArr, 1) - 1) * UBound(inputArr, 1)) / 2
    
    Dim outputIndex As Long
    Dim outputArr As Variant
    ReDim outputArr(1 To outputSize, 1 To 1) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    Dim currFirst As Long
    Dim currLowest As Long
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(inputArr, 1)
        currFirst = inputArr(i, 1)
        currLowest = currFirst - inputArr(i - 1, 1)
                
        For n = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
            Dim testLowest As Long
            testLowest = currFirst - inputArr(n, 1)
            
            If testLowest < currLowest Then currLowest = testLowest
            
            outputIndex = outputIndex + 1
            outputArr(outputIndex, 1) = currLowest
        Next n
    Next i
    
    ws.Cells(startRow, outputCol).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1)).Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Code explanation: (dataset is just for visual purposes)
Code calculates Value in a column (for instance column B) and creates array1 and and insert array into result column.

What I want to implement is repeat this code/loop n number of times and create dynamic number of arrays and then put a result of these arrays into Result column. I can't figure out how to create an array1 then array2 and so on within one loop.

One column might have 60k+ rows hence I need really light weight solution to achieve a minimum run time.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

Added picture
[image]

Comment: Why do you need multiple arrays if you don't rely on them when calculating the current array? Wrap your entire procedure body in a `For n = 1 to n`/`Next`.

Comment: @GSerg but then I will just replace array1 all the time, won't I? I need to create for instance 10 arrays and then compare values in them.

Comment: Are the columns different lengths?

Comment: @CDP1802 same length, same array size

Comment: Given your dataset, you can get your results column with a formula. And there are ways to make it adaptable to different size data sets.

Comment: If you need to have `n` separate arrays in memory all at the same time, add them to a collection or dictionary object.  For just "summing" there's no need for more than two arrays -- one for the data and then add that to the result.  For other kinds of comparisons, it may be useful.

Comment: Make the output array bigger `ReDim outputArr(1 To outputSize, 1 To 10)`  if you have 10 columns. Not sure how this will work if the columns are 60k because your outputSize will be 1.8 billion!

Comment: @Thayskills 1) The code that you posted is exactly the same as what I answered so what did you tried? 2) If I understand your explanation correctly - Ultimately you want to sum up the output of all pair columns into 1 combined array and show in 1 `Result` column?

Comment: @RaymondWu Yes, Raymond. I want your code to repeat numerous times, create numerous arrays and then make a math (sum is just an example, actually I need an average from these arrays as a result array). In other words, I need one array made out of n arrays. I've posted just your code for simplicity since logic how to do a calculations is rather sophisticated and irrelevant to my issue. I'm just asking things I can't sort out by myself (calculations is something I've been able to sort out by myself so far). Thanks again.

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks, seems perfect. Implementing to my code and stumbled upon this last issue.  `For x = 1 To outputColl.count For i = 1 To UBound(outputColl(x), 1)    Debug.Print outputColl(x)(i, 1)  Next i Next x' loop goes vertically - from first array value to Ubound in array1 and then another array first value to Ubound and so on. I want to loop horizontally, meaning first value in array1, array2, array3....array n and then second value array1, array2, array,3.....nth value in array1, array2, array3. Any leads how to write it? Thanks.

Comment: @Thayskills Well, flip both `For` loop? - `For i = 1 to outputSize: For x = 1 to outputColl.Count: Debug.Print outputColl(x)(i, 1): Next x: Next i`..? Untested

Comment: @Thayskills other way will be to change how `outputArr` is sized  so that it will be 1 2D array holding the output of all columns like what CDP1802 suggested

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your Date and Values are always in pairs and so your used columns are always even.

Basically added another loop to go over the columns and at the end of each column's  calculation, add `outputArr` into a `Collection` (`outputColl`). I have added sample of how you can iterate the collection and the rows of each array at the end.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Const startRow As Long = 2
    Const firstValueCol As Long = 2
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, firstValueCol).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(startRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    
    Dim outputSize As Long
    outputSize = ((lastRow - startRow) * (lastRow - startRow + 1)) / 2
            
    Dim outputArr As Variant
    ReDim outputArr(1 To outputSize, 1 To 1) As Variant
    
    Dim outputColl As Collection
    Set outputColl = New Collection
        
    Dim x As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For x = firstValueCol To lastCol Step 2
        Dim inputArr As Variant
        inputArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, x), ws.Cells(lastRow, x)).Value
            
        Dim outputIndex As Long
        outputIndex = 0
        
        For i = 2 To UBound(inputArr, 1)
            Dim currFirst As Long
            Dim currLowest As Long
            
            currFirst = inputArr(i, 1)
            currLowest = currFirst - inputArr(i - 1, 1)
                    
            For n = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
                Dim testLowest As Long
                testLowest = currFirst - inputArr(n, 1)
                
                If testLowest < currLowest Then currLowest = testLowest
                
                outputIndex = outputIndex + 1
                outputArr(outputIndex, 1) = currLowest
            Next n
        Next i
        
        outputColl.Add outputArr
    Next x
    
    'Loop through your collection
    For x = 1 To outputColl.Count
        
        'loop through the rows in the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(outputColl(x), 1)
            'Do your math here
            Debug.Print outputColl(x)(i, 1)
        Next i
    Next x
    
    'Dim outputCol As Long
    'outputCol = lastCol + 1
    'ws.Cells(startRow, outputCol).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1)).Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

### Sum Up Resulting Arrays

```vb
Option Explicit

' 1448 rows in source will generate 1047629 rows in destination,
' which takes about 6-7 seconds for 10 columns.
Sub WriteTricky()
' Needs 'GetTricky' and 'SumUpTwoArrays'.
    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer ' time measuring

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sColsList As String = "B,D,F,H,J,L,N,P,R,T"
    Const slrCol As String = "B" ' Last Row Column
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "V2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the source last (one-column) range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = (srCount - 1) * srCount / 2
    If sws.Rows.Count - drCount - sfRow + 1 < 0 Then Exit Sub ' will not fit
    Dim slrcrg As Range: Set slrcrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, slrCol).Resize(srCount)
    
    ' Write the 'tricky' values to the destination array.
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCols)
    Dim dData As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(sCols)
        Set scrg = slrcrg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n))
        If n > 0 Then
            aData = GetTricky(scrg)
            SumUpTwoArrays dData, aData
        Else
            dData = GetTricky(scrg)
        End If
    Next n
    
    ' Write values from destination array to the destination (one-column) range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dfcell.Resize(UBound(dData))
    dcrg.Value = dData
    
    Debug.Print Timer - dTime ' time measuring
    
End Sub

' This is Raymond Wu's logic transferred to a function.
Function GetTricky( _
    ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        If srCount = 1 Then Exit Function
        sData = .Value
    End With
            
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = (srCount - 1) * srCount / 2
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim sn As Long
    Dim currFirst As Long
    Dim currLowest As Long
    Dim testLowest As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        currFirst = sData(sr, 1)
        currLowest = currFirst - sData(sr - 1, 1)
        For sn = sr - 1 To 1 Step -1
            testLowest = currFirst - sData(sn, 1)
            If testLowest < currLowest Then currLowest = testLowest
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, 1) = currLowest
        Next sn
    Next sr
    
    GetTricky = dData

End Function

Sub SumUpTwoArrays( _
        ByRef SumData As Variant, _
        ByVal AddData As Variant) ' note 'ByRef' i.e. 'SumData' will be modified
    Dim aValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(AddData)
        aValue = AddData(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(aValue) Then
            If aValue <> 0 Then
                SumData(r, 1) = SumData(r, 1) + aValue
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: 2008, thank you for your comment, code is working perfectly. But I need to conduct mathematical operations for more columns, arrays (yours just sums up two arrays) and code is rather advanced, hard to comprehend for someone in my stage of learning. I am not able to amend code for my neeeds tho :(

Comment: It sums up as many arrays (columns) as you have column strings in `sColsList`. Could you share more detail on what you're trying to do i.e. do you need pure columns or do you need those columns processed with your tricky code e.g. in a jagged array (array of arrays)?

Comment: Added picture for better understanding, VBasic 2008.